# Equality operator for functions?

Tags: python, function, class, comparison-operators

I am building up my understanding of Python, and recently I understood that functions *must be* classes(?), and that a `def func():` just instantiates an object of class `function`. I was mindblown when I created an attribute of `func` honestly.

Lurking in `dir(func)` I noticed that indeed all the special methods such as `.__eq__` are inherited, and I wanted to play around with it:

```
def func(n):
    print(n)
    def __eq__(self,func2):
        print('hello')
```

However, it does not work:

```
>>> func.__eq__(print)
NotImplemented
```

What would it be the proper way to overload the equality operator for a function? I don't see how to overload it without having a proper `class` definition.

Comment: "recently I understood that functions must be classes" - I don't know how or where you got that idea, but it's wrong. Functions are *instances* of a class, just like any other Python object (including classes themselves), but functions are not classes.

Comment: Thank you both, you are actually both right, and I understood what is going on. What i tried is to ``import types``, to ``def equality_mine():`` my own new equality operator, and ``types.FunctionType.__eq__ = equality_mine`` to use it to overload the function equality operator: ``TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'function'``. I guess someone thought about it before me.

Comment: You can make your own classes whose instance are callable by defining a `__call__()` special method in them. Such classes can have their own `__eq__()` comparison methods, just like other classes. You can even "register" your class so that calls to `isinstance()` will consider instances of it the same as those of `types.FunctionType`. In other words instances of your own class would be (almost) "functionally" equivalent to built-in functions. `;¬)`

Comment: I think you meant "overriding" instead of "overloading"

Answer (score 1):

Because python treats all functions as objects, it might be worth thinking of creating functions as creating instances of the class `function` (which isn't documented) with the `__call__` method being the body of the function created with `def`. The actual C source of the `function` class is [on Github](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/funcobject.c) if you want to know implementation details.

With returning NotImplemented:

In Python, if objects do not override `__eq__` or `__hash__`, there is default implementations where `__hash__ = builtins.id` and `__eq__` is like `lambda self, other: self is other`. When the comparison operators return `NotImplemented`, this instructs the runtime to search for another method that does the same thing, like trying `__ne__` instead of `__eq__`, or trying operators from the parent.

```py
>>> def test(a):
...     return a
...
>>> def test2(a):
...     return a
...
>>> test == test2
False
>>> test.__eq__(test2)
NotImplemented
```

You can also test this by creating a dummy class that doesn't override `__eq__` (like how the `function` class doesn't):

```py
>>> class testcls:
...     pass
... 
>>> t1 = testcls()
>>> t2 = testcls()
>>> t1.__eq__(t2)
NotImplemented
>>> t1.__eq__(t1)
True
>>> t1 == t2
False
```

Answer (score -1):

No, functions don't have to be classes (yet they are in Python), actually. But that is another story.

Seems you misunderstand that `__eq__` is a method, i.e. you need a `class` that it belongs to in order to overload it. What you code does is defines some custom function within another function, which is valid Python code but has nothing to do with `__eq__` overloading.

Since you can't inherit function, you can't overwrite it's eq. And even if you could do that, it won't work due to some purely theoretical reasons.

Comment: Functions aren't classes in Python, they're _instances_ of the built-in `types.FunctionType`.

Comment: @martineau thx, didn't know that. But lambdas are classes, right?

Comment: No, `lambda` functions are instances of the built-in `types.LambdaType`. You can [see](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#standard-interpreter-types) for your self.

Comment: (And `types.LambdaType` is the same type as `types.FunctionType`. It's listed under two names because Guido (or maybe some other core dev) wasn't sure if they would always be the same type.)